# Should the MEID, PESN, IMEI1 and IMEI2 numbers be kept secret?

Tags: mobile, android, phone, smartphone

On my Huawei PLK-AL10, when I type `*#06#` in the dialer, a window named `MEID_IMEI` would pop up and display some random strings. Note that someone can get this information through the "Emergency call" interface, *without having to know the lock screen password.*

[image]

I'm told that only mobile phones manufactured by Huawei show the `MEID`, `PESN`, `IMEI1` and `IMEI2` information if someone tries to dial `*#06#` using the emergency call dialer. Could this be a security risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no real security risk**.

Those numbers displayed each represent a serial number of a certain piece of hardware. Cellular networks mostly use IMEI to track a stolen phone and put it on a blacklist. 
There for no attack is exposed unless someone would get your IMEI and add it to a blacklist (very unlikely).

What you should worry about is your phone that is being accessed by someone else so take good care of that!